# Python: How can i add loggings to an existing log-file (to avoid .bak files)?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

i have a Python application which is often started and closed again.
Now each time i restart my application, the existing log file is renamed from my_logging_2019-09-09.log to my_logging_2019-09-09.bak and a new log file is created.

What i want to have now is:
- each day a new file should be used
- if there is already a file for the current day, this file should be used. And instead of creating a .bak file, the new logs should be appended to the existing file.

How can i do this?

here you can see my current code:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logHandler = logging.FileHandler(path + '/my_logging{:%Y-%m-%d}.log'.format(datetime.now()))
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use TimedRotatingFileHandler instead of FileHandler, for example:

```
logHandler = logging.TimedRotatingFileHandler(path + '/my_logging.log', when="midnight", interval=1)
```

It will generate a new my_logging.log file everyday, and rename the old my_logging.log file with the date it generated

Alternatively, I tried to run your code on my side. I run the code twice but it doesn't generate a .bak file. Instead, the log appended on the same file as you expected.

```
import logging
import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger('my_application')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logHandler = logging.FileHandler('my_logging{:%Y-%m-%d}.log'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.info('log something here')
logger.info('log something there')
```

my_logging2019-09-18.log

```
2019-09-18 21:54:08,496 - my_application - INFO - log something here
2019-09-18 21:54:08,496 - my_application - INFO - log something there
2019-09-18 21:54:16,671 - my_application - INFO - log something here
2019-09-18 21:54:16,672 - my_application - INFO - log something there
```

Comment: thanks,

but is there also a way to use the date immediately as a part of the filename. 
Or is it only possible that the file is renamed after the date changed

Comment: @mak1 unfortunately it seems it is only possible the file is renamed after. I am trying to re-produce your issue but it seems no problem for me, i.e. the log can be appended in the same file with same date, no .bat file is created. Let me edit my answer to show you my testing code.